# Intersection on lists

Tags: r

i have 6 txt files split in 2 groups (A and T files).
i want import all these files in R and intersect every A file with every T file and obtain a matrix with the ratio of A over T like in this example. I was thinking of making two lists of vectors and find a way to calculate this matrix starting from them.

```
A_1.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
banana
coconut
salt
A_2.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
A_3.txt
zucchini
potato
T_1.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
banana
coconut
salt
T_2.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
banana
T_3.txt
potato
banana
coconut
```

what i want to obtains is this matrix:

```
    T_1 T_2 T_3
A_1 6   4   3
A_2 3   3   1
A_3 2   2   1
```

Could somebody can give me a tip on how to do this in R?

I read in this information in this way:

```
A_files <- list.files("/home/A/", full.names = TRUE)
T_files <- list.files("/home/T/", full.names = TRUE)
myAlist <- lapply(A_files, read.delim, header=FALSE)
myTlist <- lapply(T_files, read.delim, header=FALSE)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to obtain. Those are text files, how can you do a ratio? or do you just want to represent them as a ratio (i.e. banana/potato))

Comment: sorry i have in fact modified my question.

Comment: Given your data, which is the result? Could you add the specific output from your example dats?

Comment: i've written the result

Comment: Is that your file format already, or do you have a way of reading in the files so you could more easily tell what information comes from what file?

Comment: I've posted what i've done so far about the file importing

Comment: Okay, so it would actually be easier to work with if you just post e.g. `dput(myAlist)`. That way we have your data in its actual format, since we don't have access to the files you're reading. The reason I asked is that the original list of file content seemed like a less than ideal format, and splitting it into distinct sets of data would be a couple unnecessary steps on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do with my preferred set of tools:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
filenames <- dir(pattern = "^[AT]_\\d.txt$") 
vec <-
  lapply(filenames, fread, header = FALSE) %>% 
  set_names(filenames %>% stringr::str_remove("\\.txt$")) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "file")
vecA <- vec[file %like% "^A"]
vecT <- vec[file %like% "^T"]
vecA[vecT, on = .(V1), allow.cartesian = TRUE] %>% 
  dcast(file ~ i.file, length)
```

> ```
>    file T_1 T_2 T_3
> 1:  A_1   6   4   3
> 2:  A_2   3   3   1
> 3:  A_3   2   2   1
> ```

#### Explanation

1. Supposed all files `A_1.txt`, `A_2.txt`, ..., `T_2.txt`, `T_3.txt` are stored in the same folder, the filenames are picked.
2. All files are read into a list, the list elements are named accordingly, then they are combined into *one* data.table with an additional column which identifies the source of each row.
3. Then, the two datasets are separated in `vecA` and `vecT`. (This is just for clarity and to make the code less convoluted).
4. The two datasets are joined and the result is  reshaped from long to wide format counitng the number of common elements.

The result of the join is

```
vecA[vecT, on = .(V1), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

> ```
>     file       V1 i.file
>  1:  A_1   tomato    T_1
>  2:  A_2   tomato    T_1
>  3:  A_1 zucchini    T_1
>  4:  A_2 zucchini    T_1
>  5:  A_3 zucchini    T_1
>  6:  A_1   potato    T_1
>  7:  A_2   potato    T_1
>  8:  A_3   potato    T_1
>  9:  A_1   banana    T_1
> 10:  A_1  coconut    T_1
> 11:  A_1     salt    T_1
> 12:  A_1   tomato    T_2
> 13:  A_2   tomato    T_2
> 14:  A_1 zucchini    T_2
> 15:  A_2 zucchini    T_2
> 16:  A_3 zucchini    T_2
> 17:  A_1   potato    T_2
> 18:  A_2   potato    T_2
> 19:  A_3   potato    T_2
> 20:  A_1   banana    T_2
> 21:  A_1   potato    T_3
> 22:  A_2   potato    T_3
> 23:  A_3   potato    T_3
> 24:  A_1   banana    T_3
> 25:  A_1  coconut    T_3
>     file       V1 i.file
> ```

#### Reproducible data

This is a way to create the 6 input files from the sample dataset provided in the question:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
fread("A_1.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
banana
coconut
salt
A_2.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
A_3.txt
zucchini
potato
T_1.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
banana
coconut
salt
T_2.txt
tomato
zucchini
potato
banana
T_3.txt
potato
banana
coconut", header = FALSE) %>% 
  .[, fwrite(.(V1[-1]), V1[1]), by = cumsum(V1 %like% "^[AT]_\\d.txt$")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using base R commands. R defaults to creating factors from character vectors. It is important that you not allow that. Including the argument `as.is=TRUE` in your `read.csv` commands will preserve the character data. First make the data easily available:

```
myAlist <- list(A_1 = c("tomato", "zucchini", "potato", "banana", "coconut", 
     "salt"), A_2 = c("tomato", "zucchini", "potato"), A_3 = c("zucchini", 
     "potato"))
myTlist <- list(T_1 = c("tomato", "zucchini", "potato", "banana", "coconut", 
     "salt"), T_2 = c("tomato", "zucchini", "potato", "banana"), T_3 = c("potato", 
     "banana", "coconut"))
```

Now we create a function to find the intersection of two groups and compute the number of shared items:

```
Shared <- function(a, t) {
    length(intersect(myAlist[[a]], myTlist[[t]]))
}
```

We are taking each group in A and comparing it to each group in B, e.g A1 with B1, B2, B3, etc:

```
(A <- rep(1:3, each=3))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
(T <- rep(1:3, 3))
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Finally we compute the number of shared items:

```
nshare <- mapply(Shared, A, T)
myTbl <- matrix(nshare, 3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(A=names(myAlist), T=names(myTlist)))
myTbl
#      T
# A     T_1 T_2 T_3
#   A_1   6   4   3
#   A_2   3   3   1
#   A_3   2   2   1
```